# Updating cumulative data per time unit via trigger or via schedule

Tags: sql-server, charts

I have 100K records table that record activities of users.
I want to show some charts base on that data value per time unit. So I've created a chart base table.

Except time unit key column (1,2,3,4...) there are two more columns in the chart base table:

1. Absolute - example: 1, 2, 7, 20 ...
2. Accumulated and growing - example: 1, 3, 10 , 30 ...

Which is better?

- Update Trigger (when status change) - CPU work light only on specific record on every change to the table. Accumulative value will be pass to the next time unit by internal select.

or

- Aggregation Updating each time unit (by schedule) - CPU work hard on all records. Accumulative value will be calculated on all records till current time unit.

Comment: Yaniv, isn't your question answering itself? Or, perhaps, there is a difference in the results... is there?

Comment: I prefer the 1st approach - Update trigger. It seem more logical for me. What do you think?

Comment: Well, when I suggested that the answer is in the question, that is exactly what I meant.